# Tensorflow: How can I combine my 3D Matrix together as one whole matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, dimension

I have turned 2D vector into 3D matrices. Now I want to **combine all these 3D matrices into 1 whole 3D Matrix**. How can I do that?

I tried the following ways, but are not able to get it.

1. *np.stack*
2. *tf.pack*

My code:

```
#I got 104 files
for i in range(104):
    X3D = tf.stack(X3D[i], X3D[i+1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined what 'combine', but based on your examples it does not make sense. If you will combine many N-ranked tensors, you will get a (N+1) ranked tensor. To see why is this the case look at 1-dim, 2-dim tensors (scalars and vectors).

As of how to combine the, your code which uses [stack](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) works fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x1 = tf.random_normal((3, 3))
x2 = tf.random_normal((3, 3))

z = tf.stack([x1, x2])
with tf.Session() as session:
        print session.run(z)
```